# $G$ is a finite supersoluble group. every maximal subgroup of $G$ permutes with every $2$-maximal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ is a finite supersoluble group of order $pq^{\beta}$ such that a Sylow $q$-subgroup $Q=\langle x \rangle$ of $G$ is cyclic and $Q_{G}=\langle x^{q}\rangle$. Then every maximal subgroup of $G$ permutes with every $2$-maximal subgroup of $G$. \\\                       $Q_{G}=Cor_{G}(Q)=\cap_{g\in G}g^{-1}Qg$ \                                                   A subgroup $M$ of a $G$ is called $2$-maximal in $G$ if $H$ is a maximal subgroup of some maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$.

Comment: Define your stuff: what is $\,Q_G\;$ , what is $\,2$-maximal subgroup...?

Comment: $Q_{G}=Cor_{G}(Q)=\cap_{g\in G}g^{-1}Qg$ \\                        A subgroup $M$ of a $G$ is called $2$-maximal in $G$ if $H$ is a maximal subgroup of some maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$.

Comment: @EbruArdamoglo: Is $a=x$?

Comment: yes, its mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Calculate the commutator $[Q_G,P]$ and then $[Q_G,G]$.

**Hint:** Every 2-maximal subgroup is normal.

Comment: In case one has not already shown P is normal: Hint Hall's 1928 Sylow theorems work very well with supersolvability. Consider G/Q_G to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: I know $Q_{G}$ is 2-maximal in $G$, Another 2-maximal subgroup of $G$ ?

Comment: $P\Phi(\Phi(Q))$. I don't think there are many others. In a supersolvable group, the index of a maximal is prime, and the index of a 2-maximal subgroup is a product of two primes (pq or qq). $Q_G$ is the index $pq$, and $P\Phi(\Phi(Q))$  the index $q^2$.

Comment: Since $|G:M|$ is relatively prime to $p$, $M$ contains a Sylow $p$-subgroup. Since $P$ is normal, $M$ contains $P$. $G/P$ is abelian (cyclic), so $M/P$ is normal. So $M$ is normal.

Comment: Your note is interesting but i  can't understand why $P$ is normal?

Comment: $G/Q_G$ has order $pq$. Either $p$ or $q$ is normal, but $Q_G$ is the normal core of $Q$, not $Q$, so $P$ is normal. Technically this gives $Q_GP$ is normal, but it also gives $q$ divides $p-1$. Relevant here is $q<p$. Hall showed that $[G:N_G(P)]$ is the product of orders of chief factors, each congruent to 1 mod p. In a supersolvable group, all chief factors have prime order, so the only relevant prime is q. But q is not equivalent to 1 mod p, since q is smaller than p. Hence $[G:N_G(P)]=1$.