# Supersolvable group and nilpotent maximal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

$G$ is a supersolvable group, $|G|=pq^{b}$ ($p$ and $q$ are different prime numbers). $Q$ is a $q$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, $Q=\langle x\rangle$ and $\operatorname{Cor}_{G}(Q)=\langle x^{q}\rangle$. If $M$ is maximal subgroup of $G$ and $|G: M|=q$, then  how can I prove $M$ is nilpotent?

Comment: The hints at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420210/g-is-a-finite-supersoluble-group-every-maximal-subgroup-of-g-permutes-with also solve this easy calculation.

Comment: How Can i calculate?. Please tell me a few more hint.

Comment: Write down exactly what $G/Cor_G(Q)$ is. Find its order, its subgroups, which ones are normal, etc. Then write down exactly what $G/P$ is. Find its subgroups, which ones are normal, central, etc. Which of those subgroups is $M/P$? What does $M$ look like now?

Comment: You can show that the Sylow $p$- and $q$-subgroups of $M$ are normal. But I am voting to close since you have shown no work of your own.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we prove that $q<p$. On the contrary, if $p<q$, since $|G:Q|=p$, we get that $Q\triangleleft G$, hence $Cor_{G}(Q)=Q$, a contradiction. So $q<p$ (This implies that $M\triangleleft G$). Now as $Q$ is cyclic, we get that $G$ has a normal $q$-complement, which is the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, say $P$. Note that $Cor_{G}(Q)$ is a subgroup of every Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$, and since they are cyclic every subgroup is unique, we get that $Cor_{G}(Q)$ is the Sylow $q$-subgroup of $M$, whence $M=P\times Cor_{G}(Q)$, hence $M$ is nilpotent.

Remark that we did not use the supersolvability of $G$, and actually it can be concluded from the above discussion.